# Convert DataType

Tags: sql, integer, varchar

How can I change the datatype of a column in Teradata from Integer to VARCHAR(30) and VARCHAR to Integer but keep the fields null?

Comment: Does an `ALTER` statement not work?

Comment: The datatype of what, a table column? In what RDBMS?

Comment: @mstbaum I tried using Alter statment but it did not work

Comment: What didn't work?  What did you try, what was the result? Include these in your question.

Comment: Not much information we can go on with.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that a CAST worked.

CAST(ZEROIFNULL(NULL) AS VARCHAR(30)) as Claim_NBR